# Stop watch with current time in android studio using Java language

Tags: java, android, datetime, stopwatch

I want to make stopwatch with current time. I have two button id is `btn1` and `btn2`. I want that when I click on button one it should start calculation time from current device time and when I click on stop it should stop with calculating difference between start and stop time. For example let current time is 10.00 my stop watch calculation time from 10.00 and when I stop it the time is 10 .15 . Then it should show the time is 15 minute of work with current start and stop time. I am using Android Studio with **Java** language. Please any body help me

Comment: Pls read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: If you are totally new to Android, you should do a series of graded tutorials that will teach you the basics of Java programming in general, and programming for android in particular.

Comment: I am sure that your search engine can find a lot of useful resources, possibly even a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

> make stop watch with current time

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

Or:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ) )
```

> start calculation time from current device time

```
Instant start = Instant.now() ;
```

> when i click on stop ut should stop

```
Instant end = Instant.now() ;
```

> calculating difference between start and stop time.

```
Duration elapsed = Duration.between( start , end ) ;
```

> show the time is 15 minute of work

```
long minutesElapsed = elapsed.toMinutes() ;
```

> with current start and stop time.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ) ;
String output = 
    start.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).format( f ) +
    " to " +
    end.atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).format( f ) +
    " is " +
    minutesElapsed +
    " minutes."
;
```

Comment: I am totally new to android studio can u help me sir. I dont know how to implement this code. Can u help me by writing a complete code with inoncreateview() function

Comment: @SOFIAABBASI  No. This site is neither a free code-writing service nor a guided tutorial site. Before posting here, study the Java Tutorials proved by Oracle free of cost. Then proceed to any of the many good tutorials on Android.